# Group By and Count for All Identifiers

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to count the number of records in a table join where a flag for a column in a table is 'A', 'B' or 'C'. I also need this to return a count of 0 where no rows exist (so I need A, B and C to return every time with their relative counts).

My query

```
Select t1.Num, t2.Flag, count(*)
from t1, t2
where t1.id = t2.id
and t2.flag in ('A','B','C')
group by t1.Num, t2.flag
```

This will of course only return the below as no records exist for 'C'

```
Num  Flag  Count

1    A     3

1    B     2
```

Is there any way I can get it to return 0 for C like below?

```
Num  Flag  Count

1    A     3

1    B     2 

0    C     0
```

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax! Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like **outer join** should come into the game:

```
SQL> with
  2  t1 (id, num) as
  3    (select 1, 100 from dual union all
  4     select 2, 200 from dual
  5    ),
  6  t2 (id, flag) as
  7    (select 1, 'A' from dual union all
  8     select 2, 'B' from dual union all
  9     select 3, 'C' from dual
 10    )
 11  select nvl(t1.num, 0) num,
 12         t2.flag,
 13         count(t1.num) cnt
 14  from t2 left join t1 on t2.id = t1.id
 15  where t2.flag in ('A', 'B', 'C')
 16  group by t1.num, t2.flag;

       NUM F        CNT
---------- - ----------
       100 A          1
       200 B          1
         0 C          0

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

*Instead* of `in` you should be using a `left join`.  You appear to already have a `join`, so the query looks like:

```
Select t1.Num, f.Flag, count(t1.id)
from (select 'A' as flag from dual union all
      select 'B' as flag from dual union all
      select 'C' as flag from dual
     ) f left join t2
     on t2.flag = f.flag left join
     t1
     on t1.id = t2.id
group by t1.Num, f.flag;
```